# How to load image dataset?

Tags: python, classification

I am building an image classification application. I have my images in folders, any idea on how I can load the images so that I will be able to train the classifier?

I am new at this so any help would be appreciated! I am using python.

Thanks

Comment: What classifier are you using?

Comment: I would like to use SVM

Comment: If the images are in same folder, then iterate over the files (images) of that folder, extract pixel values from each image, arrange them in a vector. Do this for all files to fill a 2d vector